# Python GUI to scroll through photos in a window

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to develop a Python Tkinter widget that opens a window displaying a photo and allows the user to scroll through the photos using a scroll bar. For context, the idea is to be able to scroll through a timer-series of photographs.

So far I've been able to make a Tkinter canvas displaying an image, and a Tkinter "Scale" slider, but I am having trouble combining them to meet my goal. The result of the below code is an empty canvas window and a separate slider. The slider works and prints its position when moved, but no photo ever loads. I was hoping that when the bar was moved to position 3, photo 3 would load.

Any idea what I'm missing?

```
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from Tkinter import *

class ImageCanvas(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, width=720, height=480, bd=0)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', padx=4, pady=4)

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self._job = NONE
        self.slider = tk.Scale(self.root, from_=0, to=3, orient = "horizontal", command=self.updateValue)
        self.slider.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def updateValue(self, event):
        if self._job:
            self.root.after_cancel(self._job)
        self._job = self.root.after(500, self.result)

    def result(self):
        self._job=None
        print self.slider.get()
        returnedValue = self.slider.get()

class ImgTk(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.main = ImageCanvas(self)
        self.main.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.c = self.main.canvas

        self.currentImage = {}
        self.load_imgfile(images[ImageCanvas.returnedValue()])

    def load_imgfile(self, filename):
        self.img = Image.open(filename)
        self.currentImage['data'] = self.img

        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        self.c.xview_moveto(0)
        self.c.yview_moveto(0)
        self.c.create_image(0, 0, image=self.photo, anchor='nw', tags='img')
        self.c.config(scrollregion=self.c.bbox('all'))
        self.currentImage['photo'] = self.photo

images = ['/Users/Evan/Documents/Temp/4744.png', '/Users/Evan/Documents/Temp/4750.png', '/Users/Evan/Documents/Temp/4757.png']

app = ImgTk()
```

Comment: Your code is blocked at the line `self.main = ImageCanvas(self)` due to the statement `self.root.mainloop()` inside `__init__(...)` of `ImageCanvas`.  Event though you resolve this issue, the function `load_imgfile(...)` has never been executed by the command function of the slider, so no image will be shown.

Answer (score 1):

A couple suggestions may get you on the right track. Move the `self.root.mainloop()` out of the ImageCanvas class and put it at the end, after `app = ImgTk()`, as simply `mainloop()`, so it only get's called ones per instance of your app.

Also, `ImageCanvas` class doesn't have a method called `returnedValue`, and the `result` method doesn't return any value. So, add `return returnedValue` to the `result` method. Then `ImageCanvas.returnedValue()` would need to be `ImageCanvas.result()`, or you could just say `self.main.result()`.

After making these changes, the *first* image displays, more work will need to be done to get the other images to load.