# How to display a scrollable grid of images in python GUI?

Tags: python, matlab, user-interface

This question is an extension to a very [similar question in matlab.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499311/how-to-display-a-scrollable-grid-of-images-in-matlab-gui)
I am aware of the fact that I can use tkinter and a few other python libraries but I am not sure if I can exactly get the option to actually scroll through a group of images in a gui box and then perform processing operations on the images using GUI.

Comment: A very similar question has also been asked before but it did not receive a satisfactory response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40295524/python-gui-to-scroll-through-photos-in-a-window

Comment: Yes, you can scroll through a grid of images in tkinter. Your question is way too broad to answer in any more detail than that.